# Spring MVC Demo project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello I have been working on struts2 since last 2 years, I am trying to switch from struts2 to SpringMVC. However, I am facing few Difficulties.

- Too Many ways to handle the session in spring MVC
- Very different working flow, compared to struts2

To solve these difficulties I want some demo Spring MVC project, Can anyone share their project with me, so that I can read the code understand the standard Spring structure.

PS: I know this is a very stupid question, you can downvote if you want but I am seriously frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

This GitHub repo is good to start and its works fine. [ I have also fork this repo.]

[Here is the Link](https://github.com/mkyong/spring3-mvc-maven-xml-hello-world)

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Homepage usually has pretty good examples.
Heres a guide for Spring-MVC:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/